# Unable to install net-tools in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, network-manager

I would like to install the net-tools package in Ubuntu 20.04, but I am getting an error. I have tried:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Which gives me this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package ni-bds (--configure):

dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ni-kal
 ni-usrp-rio-dkms
 ni-usrp-rio
 ni-p2p
 ni-p2p-dkms
 ni-rio-dkms
 ni-bds-dkms
 ni-usrp-rio-libs
 libnip2p1
 ni-rio
 ni-fpga-interface
 ni-bds

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: You will need to fix your broken `ni-usrp-rio` installation before you can install `net-tools`.

Answer (score 1):

First run:

```
sudo apt update
```

then fix your broken packages:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

if you need to, you can configure all the packages manually using the following command but this probably won't be necessary:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

or configure an individual package (like in this example):

```
sudo dpkg --configure ni-kal
```